# connection to external MySQL in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am able to create a connection string to query the database from an external network however am unable to create a connection via new data source and therefore a dataset in order to populate a data grid view using the external information.

I have made it so that if pc name = name of dev pc it uses local server name to connect, otherwise it uses external IP.

Is there a way to create a connection for the external connection from the dev computer as its not possible to test connection and therefore gets error that its unable to connect to specified MySQL host

When inputting data into a data grid view a connection needs to be made by assigning that grid view a source. These sources come from the datasets created from the connection string by going to project, add new data source. Because the dataset needs to be accessible externally I need to create a new connection string through add new data source. Because the dev computer and database are on the same computer I cant create the connection string using that method and therefore cant create the dataset to populate the data grid view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is really not clear what yo are trying to ask here. Code is always useful as if nothing else it helps to explain your question

Comment: When inputting data into a data grid view a connection needs to be made by assiging that grid view a source. These sources come from the datasets created from the connection string by going to project, add new data source. Because the dataset needs to be accessible externally I need to create a new connection string through add new data source. Because the dev computer and database are on the same computer I cant create the connection string using that method and therefore cant create the dataset to populate the datagrid view

Comment: This woudl be better placed in the question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63385427/edit) link

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem here. Just create your data source to the local database normally. The connection string will be stored in the config file. When you deploy the application, you deploy the config file as well and you simply modify the connection string in it. How do you think developers create applications for customers that use completely different databases?

Comment: How would you modify the config file? just tried and had an issue regarding validation of the config file?

Comment: You would modify the config file by replacing the connection string that's in there with the connection string you need. If you tried to do that and it didn't work then you did it wrong. Given none of us were there when you did it, we don't know what you did so we don't know what was wrong with it. I guess there's no other way for us to find out.

Comment: Got it sorted. Changed the connection string values in app.config. Thanks for your help. I had changed the value in the .exe.config.deploy file or whatever it was, i forget now. sorry for being dumb.